# How to implement a stacktrace in C++ (from throwing to catch site)?

Tags: c++, exception, stack-trace

Is the trickery  way that we can show the entire stack trace (function+line) for an exception, much like in Java and C#, in C++?

Can we do something with macros to accomplish that for windows and linux-like platforms?

Comment: Do you mean a stacktrace for an exception thrown or a general stacktrace (usable for, e.g., log messages etc.)?

Comment: @sbi, in both cases the answer is the same :-)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616653/portable-c-stack-trace-on-exception or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564177/implementing-a-stack-trace-on-windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows it can be done using the Windows DbgHelp API, but to get it exactly right requires lots of experimenting and twiddling. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679267(VS.85).aspx for a start. I have no idea how to implement it for other platforms.

Comment: This article (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/XCrashReportPt1.aspx) will help with using DbgHelp API.

Answer (score 1):

Not without either platform specific knowledge or addition of code in each function.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on a platform which uses glibc, you can use the backtrace() functions. This are C functions, but they do work for c++ back traces too. This is of course not portable, but I doubt you will find a portable solution without additional code in every function ;-)

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html

Answer (score 0):

As of C++23 `std::stacktrace` can be used. Prior to that use [cpptrace](https://github.com/jeremy-rifkin/cpptrace) which is simple and portable.